# How to get a method to run on an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I have been doing code Katas on codewars and I wanted to see if I could run them on my computer. But while I can devise various methods I can’t get any of them to run using Command Prompt with Ruby. E.g.

```
def sum_array(arr)      
  if arr.kind_of?(Array) and arr.length > 2       
   arr.inject(:+) - arr.min - arr.max  
  else        
   0  
  end  
end 

puts sum_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Instead of returning 5 it just gives me the unmodified array.

What is the correct way for me to get the method to work on an array?

Comment: Don't need the `=` in the last line.

Comment: Indeed; you're not actually calling the method `sum_array` but instead assigning `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to the variable `sum_array`.

Answer (score 1):

Think `=` sign as 'get'.

By writing `sum_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, you're assigning the `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to `sum_array` instead of calling it, which is why it `puts` out 1, 2, 3, 4.

To call that method with `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as argument, do:

```
puts sum_array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

or

```
puts sum_array [1, 2, 3, 4]
```